# sendmail and local mail server?

Tags: evolution, email, mail-server

For testing emails I don't want to actually send an email out (and can't anyway as ISP blocks port 25).

I have installed Sendmail, and what I want to do is install a mail server on the same pc that is sending the email which I can simply send the emails to, and receive them on my pc.

so I am looking for a couple of guides.

1. install and configure sendmail correctly for this.
2. install and configure a mail server correctly for this.
3. setup mail client (evolution) to connect to the mail server

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose Sendmail over Exim, Postfix or others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/email-services.html).

Forget about sendmail, it's just too complicated for testing purpuses. You'll need a program to receive emails (that would be **postfix**) and a mail delivery agent to get the mails to your client via POP3 or IMAP. This could be **dovecot** - to use with postfix just use the `dovecot-postfix` package. The guide mentioned above explains what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty easy to enable sendmail to send mail out from localhost.  Its just a single change in the default sendmail.cnf  file , then start the sendmail service.  I do this all the time with cron scheduled jobs that send emails.   I don't remember the exact line number to edit but I know that its easy to spot if you just read through the config file.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/a/206775/111625